# Is there a number prefix like '0' or '0x' for base 10?

Tags: number-formatting, radix

I just wrote a script which parses numbers of a defined length, which often include leading 0s

Of course, if I don't *remove* those 0s, they are interpreted as a prefix meaning my number is written in octal, which isn't handy at all (and already caused me troubles, in other contexts).

*i.e.  011 is read as "9" in decimal*

For that reason, I was wondering whether such a prefix exists, and in which languages.

Seems to me that "obviousness" led to incompletness.

*I thought prefixing numbers with a "d" would make them read as base 10, but it doesn't seem to be the case in bash. (Maybe in C or Java ?)*

Octal and hexadecimal prefixes work about **everywhere**, and thinking about it, I'm quite surprised such a prefix doesn't seem to exist for decimal number.

Is that a fact, or do I ignore an easy way of avoiding such parsing problems ?